# ValueError: It seems that you are using the Keras 2 and you are passing both `kernel_size` and `strides` as integer positional arguments

Tags: python-3.x, keras, conv-neural-network, image-recognition, generative-adversarial-network

I'm a computer science undergraduate student in the 4th semester, and I'm learning about Machine Learning in this lockdown.

```
from __future__ import print_function
from keras import backend as K
K.common.set_image_dim_ordering('th') # ensure our dimension notation matches

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout
from keras.layers import Reshape
from keras.layers.core import Activation
from keras.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization
from keras.layers.convolutional import UpSampling2D
from keras.layers.convolutional import Convolution2D, AveragePooling2D
from keras.layers.core import Flatten
from keras.optimizers import SGD, Adam
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras import utils
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image, ImageOps
import argparse
import math

import os
import os.path

import glob
def generator_model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(input_dim=100, output_dim=1024))
    model.add(Activation('tanh'))
    model.add(Dense(128*8*8))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Activation('tanh'))
    model.add(Reshape((128, 8, 8), input_shape=(128*8*8,)))
    model.add(UpSampling2D(size=(4, 4)))
    model.add(Convolution2D(64, 5, 5, border_mode='same'))
    model.add(Activation('tanh'))
    model.add(UpSampling2D(size=(4, 4)))
    model.add(Convolution2D(1, 5, 5, border_mode='same'))
    model.add(Activation('tanh'))
    return model


def discriminator_model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Convolution2D(64, 5, 5, border_mode='same', input_shape=(1, 128, 128)))
    model.add(Activation('tanh'))
    model.add(AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(4, 4)))
    model.add(Convolution2D(128, 5, 5))
    model.add(Activation('tanh'))
    model.add(AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(256))
    model.add(Activation('tanh'))
    model.add(Dense(1))
    model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
    return model


def generator_containing_discriminator(generator, discriminator):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(generator)
    discriminator.trainable = False
    model.add(discriminator)
    return model


def combine_images(generated_images):
    num = generated_images.shape[0]
    width = int(math.sqrt(num))
    height = int(math.ceil(float(num)/width))
    shape = generated_images.shape[2:]
    image = np.zeros((height*shape[0], width*shape[1]),
                     dtype=generated_images.dtype)
    for index, img in enumerate(generated_images):
        i = int(index/width)
        j = index % width
        image[i*shape[0]:(i+1)*shape[0], j*shape[1]:(j+1)*shape[1]] = \
            img[0, :, :]
    return image

model = generator_model()
print(model.summary())

def load_data(pixels=128, verbose=False):
    print("Loading data")
    X_train = []
    paths = glob.glob(os.path.normpath(os.getcwd() + '/logos/*.jpg'))
    for path in paths:
        if verbose: print(path)
        im = Image.open(path)
        im = ImageOps.fit(im, (pixels, pixels), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        im = ImageOps.grayscale(im)
        #im.show()
        im = np.asarray(im)
        X_train.append(im)
    print("Finished loading data")
    return np.array(X_train)

def train(epochs, BATCH_SIZE, weights=False):
    """
    :param epochs: Train for this many epochs
    :param BATCH_SIZE: Size of minibatch
    :param weights: If True, load weights from file, otherwise train the model from scratch. 
    Use this if you have already saved state of the network and want to train it further.
    """
    X_train = load_data()
    X_train = (X_train.astype(np.float32) - 127.5)/127.5
    X_train = X_train.reshape((X_train.shape[0], 1) + X_train.shape[1:])
    discriminator = discriminator_model()
    generator = generator_model()
    if weights:
        generator.load_weights('goodgenerator.h5')
        discriminator.load_weights('gooddiscriminator.h5')
    discriminator_on_generator = \
        generator_containing_discriminator(generator, discriminator)
    d_optim = SGD(lr=0.0005, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
    g_optim = SGD(lr=0.0005, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
    generator.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer="SGD")
    discriminator_on_generator.compile(
        loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=g_optim)
    discriminator.trainable = True
    discriminator.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=d_optim)
    noise = np.zeros((BATCH_SIZE, 100))
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        print("Epoch is", epoch)
        print("Number of batches", int(X_train.shape[0]/BATCH_SIZE))
        for index in range(int(X_train.shape[0]/BATCH_SIZE)):
            for i in range(BATCH_SIZE):
                noise[i, :] = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, 100)
            image_batch = X_train[index*BATCH_SIZE:(index+1)*BATCH_SIZE]
            generated_images = generator.predict(noise, verbose=0)
            #print(generated_images.shape)
            if index % 20 == 0 and epoch % 10 == 0:
                image = combine_images(generated_images)
                image = image*127.5+127.5
                destpath = os.path.normpath(os.getcwd()+ "/logo-generated-images/"+str(epoch)+"_"+str(index)+".png")
                Image.fromarray(image.astype(np.uint8)).save(destpath)
            X = np.concatenate((image_batch, generated_images))
            y = [1] * BATCH_SIZE + [0] * BATCH_SIZE
            d_loss = discriminator.train_on_batch(X, y)
            print("batch %d d_loss : %f" % (index, d_loss))
            for i in range(BATCH_SIZE):
                noise[i, :] = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, 100)
            discriminator.trainable = False
            g_loss = discriminator_on_generator.train_on_batch(
                noise, [1] * BATCH_SIZE)
            discriminator.trainable = True
            print("batch %d g_loss : %f" % (index, g_loss))
            if epoch % 10 == 9:
                generator.save_weights('goodgenerator.h5', True)
                discriminator.save_weights('gooddiscriminator.h5', True)

def clean(image):
    for i in range(1, image.shape[0] - 1):
        for j in range(1, image.shape[1] - 1):
            if image[i][j] + image[i+1][j] + image[i][j+1] + image[i-1][j] + image[i][j-1] > 127 * 5:
                image[i][j] = 255
    return image
def generate(BATCH_SIZE):
    generator = generator_model()
    generator.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer="SGD")
    generator.load_weights('goodgenerator.h5')
    noise = np.zeros((BATCH_SIZE, 100))
    a = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, 100)
    b = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, 100)
    grad = (b - a) / BATCH_SIZE
    for i in range(BATCH_SIZE):
        noise[i, :] = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, 100)
    generated_images = generator.predict(noise, verbose=1)
    #image = combine_images(generated_images)
    print(generated_images.shape)
    for image in generated_images:
        image = image[0]
        image = image*127.5+127.5
        Image.fromarray(image.astype(np.uint8)).save("dirty.png")
        Image.fromarray(image.astype(np.uint8)).show()
        clean(image)
        image = Image.fromarray(image.astype(np.uint8))
        image.show()        
        image.save("clean.png")


def get_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--mode", type=str)
    parser.add_argument("--batch_size", type=int, default=128)
    parser.add_argument("--nice", dest="nice", action="store_true")
    parser.set_defaults(nice=False)
    args = parser.parse_args()
    return args

train(400, 10, False)

generate(1)
```

I was trying this GAN code from [this](https://github.com/llSourcell/how_to_generate_video) GitHub repository, for learning about Generative Adversarial Networks, but the below error occurred. Can you please tell me where the definitions are provided in the code? Please help me!

The Troublesome Line:-

```
train(400, 10, False)
```

This is the error:-

```
ValueError: It seems that you are using the Keras 2 and you are passing both `kernel_size` and `strides` as integer positional arguments. For safety reasons, this is disallowed. Pass `strides` as a keyword argument instead.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error arises from every addition of a `Conv2D` layer in your model. You need to change the line in your code

```
model.add(Convolution2D(64, 5, 5, border_mode='same'))
```

to something like (depending on what exactly you want)

```
model.add(Conv2D(64,kernel_size=5,strides=2,padding='same'))
```

Notice that I have explicity named the argument `strides` here because the error says I should pass it as a keyword argument.